# Working with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

I have a database in my azure cloud from where i want to authenticate users, whenever a user logs in he/she should be checked against the present username or password in the database like we do in web applications using simple select query.
i am a newbie here so please guide me i dont have very much experience of Azure cloud services

Comment: Take a look at the Mobile Apps documentation map: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box mobile services allows you to authenticate with active directory, Facebook, Google and Twitter.

You can also add your own custom authentication to a mobile services application.

Here's a good step by step tutorial that shows you how to authenticate using your own .NET backend code. In this example users are stored in an  Accounts table in a sql azure database. You could change this to simply point to your existing database in the cloud and read the connectionstring from an appsetting.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/